How concerned should I be about the level of EMI generated by simple isolated DC-DC converters?
I'm in the early prototyping stage for a system that integrates with DMX512. One of my design goals is to make the DMX interface extremely robust. To that end I'm going to be using THVD2410, which is a functional safety capable RS-485 transceiver IC that can withstand DC faults up to ±70V, plus some serious ESD. This, plus some additional external protection, means that if someone runs DMX over 3-pin XLR and accidentally plugs it into 48V phantom power from an audio system, it should survive the incident.
My plan right now is to use an isolated DC-DC converter to produce a separate isolated 5V rail for the DMX interfaces, then use an optoisolator for the data lines. It's transmit-only and DMX512 is only 250Kbaud, so it's not particularly challenging. However, there's a potential that I'll want to sell this as a product later, and I'd like to avoid shooting myself in the foot this early in the process by picking an isolated DC-DC converter design that will never pass EMC. I know they're not always the quietest of supplies, and I've heard stories from folks who had designs only just scrape through testing due to cheap-and-dirty isolated supplies.
A quick, easy, and cheap approach would be something like a VPS8702 and VPT87BB-01A followed by a linear regulator. The datasheets are in Chinese but the topology is standard and the key specs are easy to intuit - 5V in, it switches at about 340kHz, the transformer has a 1.11 ratio, rectify that with schottky diodes, stick a cap on the output, job done.
The driver IC has a 126V/us slew rate, so that's about 40ns for a 5V swing, which seems fast enough to be a potential concern. I'm not going to be pulling much current from the isolated supply (just two or three RS-485 ICs), so I imagine the majority of the dI/dt is just going to be going back and forth in the primary side of the transformer.
How seat-of-the-pants is this likely to be in terms of meeting typical EMC standards, particularly in radiated emissions? Are there any particular design gotchas here for EMC? Naturally I'll be following good practice layout and be using an appropriate board stackup.

Have you tested it for compliance?

I'm in the design phase, looking for advice from folks who have built these types of isolated supply before I do a bunch of design work and order a prototype.

My best advice would be to simulate it with resonable parasitics in your main loop on primary and secondary side. You can check conducted compliance via LISN with resonable accuracy. For radiated, it’s strongly dependent on your layout and transformer build-up.

An IC like that would never go anywhere near my designs. Chinese "cheap but doesn't work" quality aside, how do you know it won't go EOL tomorrow?

Do not assume that using an OTS part will mean that EMC compliance is going to occur first time. If you must do OTS then a little bench homework with the scope can warn you of an impending problem before pcb layout. Try to shut up the power supply by hanging    filter parts around it. If you need too many parts then google another OTS DC/DC. You should end up with some extra filter parts that wont use up too much space and not cost too much. App notes can be a guide to filter part selection. Enter your pre benched filter circuits on the schematic and then it can get drafted without major concern.
